# Image Positioning Issue in html/css

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have the following code:

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Merriweather|Open+Sans');

.blogmaster {
  display: flex;
  margin: 60px;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.blogmaster div {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 500px;
}

@media all and (max-width: 500px) {
  .blogmaster {
    flex-flow: wrap;
    margin: 20px;
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
  }
}

.container1 {
 display: flex;
 padding: 20px;
  justify-content: center;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.square:hover {
  -webkit-transform: translate(20px, -10px);
  -ms-transform: translate(10px, -10px);
  transform: translate(10px, -10px);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 5px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
  box-shadow: 0 5px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
}

.square {
  position: relative;
  height: 100% !important;
  padding:3px;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: 0px 5px 20px #D9DBDF;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.mask {
  clip: rect(0px, 450px, 220px, 0px);
  border: 5px solid #555;
  border-radius: 4px;
  position: absolute;
  width:100%;
  height: 100%;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  z-index:1;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
.mask{
  width: 100% !important;
}
}

.h11 {
  margin: auto;
  text-align: left;
  margin-top: 240px;
  padding-left: 30px;
  padding-right: 30px;
  font-family: 'Merriweather', serif;
  font-size: 24px;
}

p9 {
  text-align: justify;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #C8C8C8;
  line-height: 18px;
  padding-left: 30px;
  padding-right: 30px;
  display: block;
}

.button56 {
  background-color: #3EDD84;
  color: white;
  width: 100px;
  padding: 10px 18px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  margin: 15px 70px 13px 30px;
  font-size: 12px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-family: 'merriweather';
}

.parent-div {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  justify-content: center;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  .parent-div {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="section-title">
    <h2>Featured Blogs Of The Day</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="parent-div">
    <div class="child-div">
      <div class="blogmaster">
        <div class="column1">
          <div class="row1">
            <div class="container1">
              <div class="square">
                <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1504610926078-a1611febcad3?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=e1c8fe0c9197d66232511525bfd1cc82&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1100&q=80" class="mask" style="border: 5px solid #555">
                <div class="h11">“Chances Of My Uni/College Admission?”</div>
                <p9>It is that time of the year again (yay!) where we — high school students — are supposed to fill out the applications and land in our dream Universities/Colleges!</p9>

                <div><a href="https://m-hussainomer03.medium.com/chances-of-my-uni-college-admission-20bc0efec0af" target="_" class="button56">Read More</a></div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- new start of blog -->
    <div class="parent-div">
      <div class="child-div">
        <div class="blogmaster">
          <div class="column1">
            <div class="row1">
              <div class="container1">
                <div class="square">
                  <img src="https://www.isfasports.gr/image/cache/data/products/pr_3-1100x1100.jpg" class="mask" style="border: 5px solid #555">
                  <div class="h11">My Career Advice To You: Take These Steps...</div>
                  <p9>Humans tend to make mistakes — and its completely normal as it results in the growth and development of an individual — either psychologically or physically.</p9>

                  <div><a href="https://m-hussainomer03.medium.com/my-career-advice-to-you-take-these-steps-to-ultimate-prosperity-6c0687ce9c9f" target="_" class="button56">Read More</a></div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>





</section>
<!-- End blogs Section -->
```

So I have the above code embedded in my website, and so when I view my website on a **smaller screen, my output looks like this:**

[image]

The width of the image is not fitted to the whole card. By "fitted" I mean **just the width and not the height**. Like, in other words, I just want the width of the image to stretch. That is all. The height of the image is fine.

### Expected Outputs

**On Larger Screen:**

[image]

This part is already working for me, but I am just showing you in case. When giving suggestions, Please do not modify this part of the code that is working for larger screens. The output of the code I sent above is **exactly what I am looking for on larger screens**

**On smaller Screens:**

[image]

So on smaller screens, I just would like the image to stretch a bit more to the end of the card. That is it. The height and everything else is fine. Any suggestions on how I can accomplish this and making the width of the image stretch out to the card?

### Edited

This is the output I am getting on small screen now. It still does not fit the card
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Hi Here I have fixed your issue.
- Try to understand the box model CSS. It will help you create any kind of layouts in HTML/CSS.
- [MDN Box model](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/The_box_model)

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Merriweather|Open+Sans');

.blogmaster {
  display: flex;
  margin: 60px;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.container1 {
 display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
 padding: 20px;
  justify-content: center;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.square {
  margin: 20px;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 500px;
  height: 100% !important;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: 0px 5px 20px #D9DBDF;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.square:hover {
  -webkit-transform: translate(20px, -10px);
  -ms-transform: translate(10px, -10px);
  transform: translate(10px, -10px);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 5px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
  box-shadow: 0 5px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
}

.square .square-image img{
 width: 100%;
  height: 250px;
  object-fit: cover;
  border-top-left-radius: 4px;
 border-top-right-radius: 4px;
}
.square .square-details{
  padding: 20px 30px 30px;
}

.h11 {
  margin: auto;
  text-align: left;
  font-family: 'Merriweather', serif;
  font-size: 24px;
}

p {
  text-align: justify;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #C8C8C8;
  line-height: 18px;
  display: block;
}

.button56 {
  background-color: #3EDD84;
  color: white;
  width: 100px;
  padding: 10px 18px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  font-size: 12px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-family: 'merriweather';
}

.parent-div {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  justify-content: center;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  .parent-div {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
}
<section>
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="section-title">
    <h2>Featured Blogs Of The Day</h2>
  </div>

  <div class="row1">
            <div class="container1">
              <div class="square">
                <div class="square-image">
                                  <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1504610926078-a1611febcad3?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=e1c8fe0c9197d66232511525bfd1cc82&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1100&q=80">
                </div>

                <div class="square-details">
                  <h3 class="h11">“Chances Of My Uni/College Admission?”</h3>
                <p>It is that time of the year again (yay!) where we — high school students — are supposed to fill out the applications and land in our dream Universities/Colleges!</p>
                  <div><a href="https://m-hussainomer03.medium.com/chances-of-my-uni-college-admission-20bc0efec0af" target="_" class="button56">Read More</a></div>
                </div>
               
              </div>
              <div class="square">
                <div class="square-image">
                                  <img src="https://www.isfasports.gr/image/cache/data/products/pr_3-1100x1100.jpg">
                </div>

                <div class="square-details">
                  <h3 class="h11">My Career Advice To You: Take These Steps...</h3>
                <p>Humans tend to make mistakes — and its completely normal as it results in the growth and development of an individual — either psychologically or physically.</p>
                  <div><a href="https://m-hussainomer03.medium.com/my-career-advice-to-you-take-these-steps-to-ultimate-prosperity-6c0687ce9c9f" target="_" class="button56">Read More</a></div>
                </div>
               
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>


</section>
<!-- End blogs Section -->
```

Comment: Hi, I have added my output in the above post under "Edited". Please take a look at it. Thanks

Comment: Hi, @abia-omer I have reviewed your code. You have to change the structure of the code and you need to learn some box model css. I have fixed your issue pls check

Comment: I used your code but I am still getting the same output that I have shown under "Edited"

Answer (score 0):

In css, you should remove or change height of .mark to auto

```
.mask {
     ...
     height: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be achieved with `relative` display, `width` set `100%` and `height` set to an absolute height in `px`.

All of my changes:

```
.mask {
  ...
  position: relative;
  min-width:100%;
  width:100%;
  height: 218px;
  top:-5px;
  left:-5px;
  ...
}
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Merriweather|Open+Sans');

.blogmaster {
  display: flex;
  margin: 60px;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.blogmaster div {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 500px;
}

@media all and (max-width: 500px) {
  .blogmaster {
    flex-flow: wrap;
    margin: 20px;
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
  }
}

.container1 {
 display: flex;
 padding: 20px;
  justify-content: center;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.square:hover {
  -webkit-transform: translate(20px, -10px);
  -ms-transform: translate(10px, -10px);
  transform: translate(10px, -10px);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 5px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
  box-shadow: 0 5px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
}

.square {
  position: relative;
  height: 100% !important;
  padding:3px;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: 0px 5px 20px #D9DBDF;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.mask {
  clip: rect(0px, 450px, 220px, 0px);
  border: 5px solid #555;
  border-radius: 5px;
  position: relative;
  min-width:100%;
  width:100%;
  height: 218px;
  top:-5px;
  left:-5px;
  z-index:1;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
.mask{
  width: 100% !important;
}
}

.h11 {
  margin: auto;
  text-align: left;
  margin-top: 240px;
  padding-left: 30px;
  padding-right: 30px;
  font-family: 'Merriweather', serif;
  font-size: 24px;
}

p9 {
  text-align: justify;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #C8C8C8;
  line-height: 18px;
  padding-left: 30px;
  padding-right: 30px;
  display: block;
}

.button56 {
  background-color: #3EDD84;
  color: white;
  width: 100px;
  padding: 10px 18px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  margin: 15px 70px 13px 30px;
  font-size: 12px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-family: 'merriweather';
}

.parent-div {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  justify-content: center;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  .parent-div {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="section-title">
    <h2>Featured Blogs Of The Day</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="parent-div">
    <div class="child-div">
      <div class="blogmaster">
        <div class="column1">
          <div class="row1">
            <div class="container1">
              <div class="square">
                <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1504610926078-a1611febcad3?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=e1c8fe0c9197d66232511525bfd1cc82&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1100&q=80" class="mask" style="border: 5px solid #555">
                <div class="h11">“Chances Of My Uni/College Admission?”</div>
                <p9>It is that time of the year again (yay!) where we — high school students — are supposed to fill out the applications and land in our dream Universities/Colleges!</p9>

                <div><a href="https://m-hussainomer03.medium.com/chances-of-my-uni-college-admission-20bc0efec0af" target="_" class="button56">Read More</a></div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- new start of blog -->
    <div class="parent-div">
      <div class="child-div">
        <div class="blogmaster">
          <div class="column1">
            <div class="row1">
              <div class="container1">
                <div class="square">
                  <img src="https://www.isfasports.gr/image/cache/data/products/pr_3-1100x1100.jpg" class="mask" style="border: 5px solid #555">
                  <div class="h11">My Career Advice To You: Take These Steps...</div>
                  <p9>Humans tend to make mistakes — and its completely normal as it results in the growth and development of an individual — either psychologically or physically.</p9>

                  <div><a href="https://m-hussainomer03.medium.com/my-career-advice-to-you-take-these-steps-to-ultimate-prosperity-6c0687ce9c9f" target="_" class="button56">Read More</a></div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>



</section>
<!-- End blogs Section -->
```